# Loading <audio> source - Firefox gets into readyState 2 and Chrome into 4

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to connect an `HTMLAudioElement` into the Web Audio API (`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`). I set `src` followed by calling `load()`.

Now while in Chromium this gets me from `readyState` `0` (`HAVE_NOTHING`) to `4` (`HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`), so a follow-up `play()` succeeds. But in Firefox I only get to state `2` (`HAVE_CURRENT_DATA`) and nothing else happens.

Am I missing a crucial step?

---

**Edit:** Here is my debug information:

`|              | FF Init | FF Load | Ch Init | Ch Load |
|readyState    | 0       | 2       | 0       | 4       |
|preload       |         |         | auto    | auto    |
|duration      | NaN     | 186.45  | NaN     | 186.44  |
|error         | null    | null    | null    | null    |
|networkState  | 0       | 1       | 0       | 1       |`

At least from this list, the only difference in initial data is the `preload` value in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So adding `preload = "auto"` after creating the media element (to match the default it obviously has in Chromium) makes it work in Firefox, too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this has anything to do with your question directly, but since I found your question when researching another problem, I'll add my two cents to help others who come here with a HAVE_CURRENT_DATA related Firefox issue...:

Found out that apparently Firefox **resets** readyState to HAVE_CURRENT_DATA after it has played the audio, i.e. in "oncanplaythrough" it was "HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA", but then after playing it went back to "HAVE_CURRENT_DATA" - maybe because there are no more frames to play? You can still play the audio with another call to "play", only the readyState is a bit confusing.

So, be careful when reusing audio...